# Unable to display data using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, netcdf

This is my first attempt to plot using matplotlib. I am trying to plot a netCDF file data of geopotential height using matplotlib and I get a blank image. There are no coastlines or anything. Just a blank screen.
My data ranges from 5 N to 40 N and from 65 E to 100 E.

I printed out the values of lat, lon and hgt and they are all valid.

Here is my code -

```
nc_f = './hgt_500_2014_12_5_00Z.nc'  # Your filename
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_f, 'r')  # Dataset is the class behavior to open the file

lats = nc_fid.variables['lat'][:]
lons = nc_fid.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc_fid.variables['time'][:]
hgt = nc_fid.variables['hgt'][:] 


hgt_units = nc_fid.variables['hgt'].units

nc_fid.close()

lon_0 = lons.mean()
lat_0 = lats.mean()


m = Basemap(width=5000000,height=3500000,
        resolution='l',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=40,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
xi, yi = m(lon, lat)

cs = m.pcolor(xi,yi,np.squeeze(hgt))


m.drawparallels(np.arange(5., 40., 5.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(65., 100., 5.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
cbar.set_label(hgt_units)

plt.title('Geopotential Height')

plt.show()
```

I also get this error when I run python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 69, in on_draw_event
buf, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
NotImplementedError: Surface.create_for_data: Not Implemented yet.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 69, in on_draw_event
buf, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
NotImplementedError: Surface.create_for_data: Not Implemented yet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may write just like `lons = nc_fid.variables['lon']`.
2. Check your lat-lon values they have to cover your region of  from 5 N to 40 N and from 65 E to 100 E.
3. `drawstates()` does not work for your region this command draw states boundaries for US.
4. Check  other GUI backends: TkAgg, WX, QTAgg, QT4Agg like:

   `import matplotlib`

   `matplotlib.use('Agg')`
5. It may be problem with cairo library

Comment: 100 % right ! I just installed cairo and got it to work !!! Thanks much !